# How can I have the average of columns indexed by datetime which are inside of a dictionary of dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have 7 sets of data from different sensors that were logging data every 30 min from Jun/2017 to May/2018. I performed some calculations for each and now I want to have one averaged series. Each series does not have same size, there are some gaps and measurements that started or ended earlier/late in one but not the others. Therefore, I would like to have an average of each specific date and time for whatever data I have, if only two of them have information, I want that average, if only one has, repeat it in the new column.

I ended up having a dictionary (sfs) with each of the sensor inside as dataframe (sfs['50'], sfs['51']....)
This is the list I was using in the loops:
sensors=['50','51','52','53','54','56','58'] #keys of the sfs dictionary (number of the sensors)

And I only want the average of 'SFD': sfs[sensors].SFD

This is how some of the data looks like:

```
sfs['50'].SFD.head()
Out[406]: 
datetime
2017-05-30 15:30:00    108.3570
2017-05-30 16:00:00    103.2061
2017-05-30 16:30:00    103.5196
2017-05-30 17:00:00     89.0948
2017-05-30 17:30:00     71.2196
Name: SFD, dtype: float64
```

```
sfs['50'].SFD.tail()
Out[413]: 
datetime
2018-05-24 10:30:00    57.0931
2018-05-24 11:00:00    58.0127
2018-05-24 11:30:00    62.0369
2018-05-24 12:00:00    67.6476
2018-05-24 12:30:00    72.9600
```

```
sfs['53'].SFD.head()
Out[409]: 
datetime
2017-05-30 16:00:00    61.0546
2017-05-30 16:30:00    54.2241
2017-05-30 17:00:00    45.3321
2017-05-30 17:30:01    31.7433
2017-05-30 18:00:01    24.1680
```

```
sfs['53'].SFD.tail()
Out[414]: 
datetime
2018-05-24 11:00:01    39.5086
2018-05-24 11:30:01    44.4543
2018-05-24 12:00:00    48.9744
2018-05-24 12:30:01    52.1892
2018-05-24 13:00:01    50.6103
```

```
sfs['56'].SFD.head()
Out[408]: 
datetime
2017-08-03 14:30:00    12.6939
2017-08-03 15:00:00     9.9883
2017-08-03 15:30:00     4.9856
2017-08-03 16:00:00     1.6739
2017-08-03 16:30:00     0.2660
```

```
sfs['56'].SFD.tail()
Out[415]: 
datetime
2018-05-24 11:30:00    31.6521
2018-05-24 12:00:00    33.9017
2018-05-24 12:30:00    37.2533
2018-05-24 13:00:00    37.0519
2018-05-24 13:30:00    36.7118
```

I thought about using groupby but it doesn't work in dict.
Tried to force sum and divide but I get lots of NAN because of the gaps, for example: (sfs['50'].SFD + sfs['51'].SFD)/2

So the expected is to have a series with the averaged values of SFD, taking into account the minutes in datetime. Thus, if a measurement is on 2018-05-24 12:30:01 it can be averaged with 2018-05-24 12:30:00. Also when there's only one date and time with measure, that can be just copied to the averaged series (instead of becoming NAN).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you merge all dataframes using `pd.concat` after adding a column in each of them denoting of the sensor id. Then you can use any method of dataframes including groupby:

```py
data = pd.concat([df.assign(sensor_id=key) for key, df in sfs.items()], axis=0, sort=False)

# Then for example for global average:
sensor_averages = data.groupby(sensor_id).mean()
# For daily averages
daily_averages = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D")).mean()
```

Does this help?

Comment: It actually gives me what I need by changing freq to 30min. @qmeeus you rock!